# SSL certificate not working while making curl request - Sectigo AddTrust External CA Root expired

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

While I try to open some of domains like https://tracking.buyhatke.com , https://s1.ripple.com , they work perfectly fine, but when I try to make a curl request to these pages from terminal, it says the certificates have expired. In browser , the certificates show that there is long time to expiry.

```
curl "https://tracking.buyhatke.com"
curl "https://s1.ripple.com"
```

Can anyone guide me what is wrong here ? And it started happening today, all of a sudden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this happened because of the issuing Root CA certificates. This can be fixed on Ubuntu 16 in this way :-

```
 1. Edit /etc/ca-certificates.conf
 2. Remove mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
 3. sudo apt update && sudo apt install ca-certificates && sudo update-ca-certificates -f -v
```

That fixed it for me

Edit

Adding some useful stuff which can help us fix it client side and server side based on your needs

https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/fixing_the_addtrust_root_expiration

Answer (score 0):

Same here for our domains, but they are expiring in a year. It's also the same for sonarcloud.io. All these domains have a common CA in their certificate chain which has expired.

```
openssl s_client -connect s1.ripple.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
```

I'm currently investigating on how to move on with this so I have no answer to give you, just the reason for why it fails at the moment.

Comment: See related issue and possible fix here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232445/https-connection-to-specific-sites-fail-with-curl-on-macos/232446#comment475027_232446

Answer (score 0):

As stated it is due to the expiration of the AddTrust_External_Root certificate

Here is a quick detailed way to fix it:

1. remove AddTrust_External_Root.crt from your system (usually found in `/etc/ssl/certs`)
2. remove or comment the "mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root" line from `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`
3. run sudo `update-ca-certificates`  (or if it doesn't work, try the version proposed by @Prashant Singh )